# Remove corresponding item when delete button is clicked. BackboneJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am currently learning BackboneJs and trying to understand how Backbone handles events. I have a simple list of items and each item has a `delete` button right next to it. I'm trying to figure out why the click event(Delete button) is registered in the console but the item is not removed. Here's what I have:

```
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Vehicle
});


/*************
single view
**************/
var VehicleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'vehicle',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get("title") + " Registration Number is: " + this.model.get("regiNum") + " <button class='delete-btn'>Delete</button>");
        this.$el.attr("id", this.model.id);
        return this;
    }
});

/*************
Collection View
*************/
var VehiclesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('remove', this.vehicleRemove, this);
    },
    events: {
        "click .delete-btn": "vehicleRemove"
    },
    vehicleRemove: function(vehicle) {
        this.$("li#" + vehicle.id).remove()  // this is not working. the item is not being removed
        console.log('Delete button clicked')    // this is registered in the console log
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.model.each(function(vehicle) {
            var vehicleView = new VehicleView({
                model: vehicle
            });
            self.$el.append(vehicleView.render().$el);
        })
    }
});


var vehicles = new Vehicles([
    new Vehicle({
        id: 1,
        title: "Toyota",
        regiNum: "453454624"
    }),
    new Vehicle({
        id: 2,
        title: "Honda",
        regiNum: "daf4526"
    }),
    new Vehicle({
        id: 3,
        title: "Audi",
        regiNum: "jlkjfa34"
    })
])

var vehiclesView = new VehiclesView({
    el: "#container",
    model: vehicles
});
vehiclesView.render();
```

Please help me out or point me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an item view, it's better to give it the functionality for removing itself. This way you don't have to hack your way reading stuff from DOM to find the related model based on the clicked item view element.

Also, you should use the `remove()` method of Backbone.View rather than the jQuery `remove()` method, because it safely removes the backbone events registered on the view, as well as calls jQuery `remove()` to remove the element from DOM.

You can call `model.destroy()` which will signal your persistence layer to remove the model and removes it from collection as well. Since you don't have a persistence layer in this example, I'm triggering a custom event on the item view's model which is handled in the collection for removing the model from it (model events propagates to it's collection).

There is no need to manually initialize models in a collection by yourself, backbone does it automatically, that's what the collections `model` property is for.

You should use some sort of templating engine rather than doing string manipulation in the view for rendering, you have `_.template()` at your disposal anyway.

Also, as dskoda1 already mentioned, you shouldn't pass a Backbone.Collection using the `model` option, model and collection are two options that will be detected by Backbone.view. Even if it does no harm, it's still very confusing.

```js
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Vehicle,
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('delete', this.remove);
  }
});
var VehicleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  className: 'vehicle',
  template: _.template($('#vehicle-template').html()),
  events: {
    "click .delete-btn": "vehicleRemove"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  vehicleRemove: function(vehicle) {
    this.remove();
    //this.model.destroy(); /* The collection should have a url */
    this.model.trigger('delete', this.model);
  },
});
var VehiclesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "ul",
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(vehicle) {
      var vehicleView = new VehicleView({
        model: vehicle
      });
      this.$el.append(vehicleView.$el);
    }, this)
  }
});

var vehicles = new Vehicles([{
  id: 1,
  title: "Toyota",
  regiNum: "453454624"
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "Honda",
  regiNum: "daf4526"
}, {
  id: 3,
  title: "Audi",
  regiNum: "jlkjfa34"
}]);

var vehiclesView = new VehiclesView({
  el: "#container",
  collection: vehicles
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="vehicle-template">
  <%=title%>Registration Number is:
    <%=regiNum%>
      <button class='delete-btn'>Delete</button>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A useful atrribute you might want to use on the buttons would be `data-id`. Setting this value to the models id would allow you to more cleanly select the correct model for deletion. The new button html would now be:

```
    "<button class='delete-btn' data-id=" + this.model.get('id') + ">Delete</button>"
```

Having buttons like this, the new click event could be fired as such:

```
    vehicleRemove: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Good practice for button clicks
        var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id'); //Id of model clicked

        //Only one of these next two lines needs to be used
        this.collection.remove(id); //If not persisting to server
        this.collection.remove(id).destroy() //If persisting to server
    },
```

Also, when you instantiate your VehiclesView, since you're passing it a collection called `vehicles`, that attribute should really be called `collection`, not `model`. An attribute named `model` is typically used on a single model view, or to represent which `model` a `collection` represents. The appropriate changes would need to be made inside of `VehiclesView`, i.e. replace every instance of the word `model` with `collection`.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

`this.remove()` ?

At this point, Backbone already knows which model you're trying to delete so there is no need to specify a jQuery selector.

Of course, .remove() is only going to remove the element from the DOM.  Are you looking for model.destroy() which will send a DELETE command to the server?

Comment: `this.remove()` works but now it deletes all three items when any one of the buttons is clicked.  Is it possible to delete an item when the a corresponding delete button is clicked instead of all items?

Right now I'm only working on how to remove the element from the DOM not from the server but thanks for that piece of info!